# Garage door won't close completely

Tags: doors, garage

After losing power and operating the door manually and causing the cable to come off the drum, the door now will not close completely.

the cable is not crossed. there are no wedged rollers. Everything is clear and it works fine until the last six inches. Also, there is a great amount of upward pressure from the springs. It it possible that the springs are now, too tight? Please help!!!

Comment: Did you have to rewind the tension cable? If so disconnect the opener from the door make sure it will close without having to push down or only a light down pressure If the door springs up you may need to unloop 1 wrap. The other possibility is a stop flag got moved or some doors have a adjustment potentiometer that may need to be adjusted it thinks the door has hit the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, you may have an extra wrap on the drum. Be very careful. Those doors are heavier than they seem when the springs are working properly.

Comment: Can you post a photo, please?  Welcome to Home Improvement.  Please take the tour to get the best out of this site:  https://diy.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: I decided to take some tension off the springs. That did the trick. I took a half turn off each spring. Thanks everyone.